# How to light up multiple lines on an LED display?

Tags: arduino, display, words, led

I am working on an LED display project and trying to show some words on the display, though I can't get continuous lines to light up. Below is the code.

```
int greenPin = 7;
int redPin = 6;
int stbPin = 2;
int clkPin = 3;
int aPin = 4;
int bPin = 5;
int delayTime = 1;
int i = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stbPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clkPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(aPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(aPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(bPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(stbPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(clkPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(stbPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(aPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(bPin, LOW);
  twoLines(B11111111, B11111111, B00000000, B00000000, B11111111, B11111111, B00000000, B00000000);
  digitalWrite(aPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(bPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(stbPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
}

void twoLines( byte br, byte dr, byte ar, byte cr, byte bg, byte dg, byte ag, byte cg) {
  byte Garr[] = { ag, bg, cg, dg };
  byte Rarr[] = { ar, br, cr, dr };

  for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    for (byte mask = 11111111; mask > 0; mask >>= 1) {
      digitalWrite(clkPin, LOW); // delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
      if (Rarr[i] & mask) {
        digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
      } else {
        digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
      }
      if (Garr[i] & mask) {
        digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
      } else {
        digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
      }
      delay(2);
      digitalWrite(clkPin, HIGH);
      delay(2);
    }
  }
}
```

Right now, I can at most only light up two rows, but I want the capability to be able to light up three rows at once to create letters. Help of any kind is appreciated. Below is also how the LED display looks like.

[image: LED Display]

Comment: How are you providing power to your LEDs? cause frankly you got lots of them and I doubt Arduino can supply that much current

Comment: I am using just an Arduino. You may be right; there may not be enough current. Are there any alternatives you would recommend?

Comment: One bug I see in the program is in the line "for (byte mask = 11111111; mask > 0; mask >>= 1) {". The 11111111 should be B11111111 (or 0xFF to be more standard) instead. 11111111 is a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this first thing you do, read the data sheet of your LED and see how much current they draw. If you got like 100 LED and each draw 20 mA, that would be 2 Amps and not only Arduino can not supply it, you are risking burning your Arduino. After you figured out how much current your system needs, you gotta use a power source that can handle it. You got several options, for example a BJT is a current amplifier but it complicates the design and needs some background in electrical engineering. The other option would be using external power sources such as batteries or wall plugs. Then, you just need to buy a good adapter or voltage regulator that can handle your current need. Also, in that case you will need some sort of relay to control the leds with your Arduino. What Relay does is that it lets you turn it on and off with micro controller logic, but when it is on it uses an external power source.